# How can I assign factor levels to empty categories?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a factor that theoretically can assume any value between 0 and 8. I wish to assign levels to each of these values; i have chosen birds as an example. However, some categories are empty which leads R to just assign the level to the next non-empty category. In my dataset this is a problem because it is updated regularly and the formerly empty categories might be no longer empty, but the assignment of factor levels is messed up.

Is there any way to assign levels in R in a more specific way? In SPSS it is possible to assign value labels and this doesn't depend on the categories actually being used.

Thank you!

```
x <- factor(c(1,3,5,6,7,6,5,3,1,8,1,6,7))

#the levels are supposed to correspond to the following values:
#0="blackbird" 
#1="eagle"
#2="owl"
#3="sparrow" 
#4="vulture"
#5="falcon" 
#6="dove" 
#7="seagull"
#8="penguin"

levels(x) <- c("blackbird", "eagle", "owl", "sparrow", "vulture", "falcon", "dove", "seagull", "penguin")

#now the levels do not correspond to the intended birds
```

Comment: @d.b I guess OP wants to do something like this ```factor(c(1,3,5,6,7,6,5,3,1,8,1,6,7), levels = c("blackbird", "eagle", "owl", "sparrow", "vulture", "falcon", "dove", "seagull", "penguin"))``` which well gives them NAs.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it!

Comment: @M-M please post this as an answer so that Jonathan will be able to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik That would give a vector of NAs. maybe the actual problem is a bit different.

Comment: The solution by @d.b actually worked, R now assigns the levels correctly despite categories being empty.

Comment: @JonathanFries levels and values should be the same. You can't have numbers as values and then levels as categories. **It's level not label!!!**

Comment: ```x <- factor(, levels = c("blackbird", "eagle", "owl", "sparrow", "vulture", "falcon", "dove", "seagull", "penguin"));
y <- factor(levels(x)[c(1,3,5,6,7,6,5,3,1,8,1,6,7)], levels = levels(x))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can account for the missing categories using `levels`. `levels` defines the possible values that `x` could have taken.

```
x = factor(c(1,3,5,6,7,6,5,3,1,8,1,6,7), levels = 0:8)
x
# [1] 1 3 5 6 7 6 5 3 1 8 1 6 7
#Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

If your values correspond to some other values, store them in a named vector.

```
y = setNames(object = c("blackbird", "eagle", "owl", "sparrow", "vulture", "falcon", "dove", "seagull", "penguin"),
             nm = 0:8)
y
#          0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8 
#"blackbird"     "eagle"       "owl"   "sparrow"   "vulture"    "falcon"      "dove"   "seagull"   "penguin"
```

If you want to get the other value from factor, subset using the vector names.

```
y[x]
#        1         3         5         6         7         6         5         3         1         8         1         6         7 
#  "eagle" "sparrow"  "falcon"    "dove" "seagull"    "dove"  "falcon" "sparrow"   "eagle" "penguin"   "eagle"    "dove" "seagull"
```